# Flink Checkpoint failed- missing subtask respond

Tags: apache-flink, checkpoint

Checkpoint failed after time out. We observed there has some subtask didn't respond. Any idea will cause this problem?

**Job Context:**

Parallelism: 5

Data Volume: Under 40k

BackPressure: send to another API at the end of the job which may take some time there.

[missing subtask respond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faRh6.png)
External Call:

```
  Future<> future = Producer.send(topic, genericRecord, dataSetID);
  future.get();

  return Boolean.TRUE;
```

Comment: Can you share more about how the connection to the external API is handled? From what you've said, the problem is almost certainly there.

Comment: That is a java asynchronous call which the underhood is implemented by Scala. Do you mean the asynchronous call failed, I couldn't figure out why it wait more than 10 mins for this kind of subtask. @DavidAnderson

Answer (score 0):

What seems likely here is that `future.get()` blocks, and for whatever reason, fails to return within the checkpoint timeout interval.

What I can suggest is that you use Flink's [RichAsyncFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html) instead. This will have the advantage that the subtasks won't be blocked, thereby allowing checkpoints to complete.

RichAsyncFunction will checkpoint the unresolved futures, and re-issue those requests when recovering from failure.

Comment: If I remove the future.get(), it may resolve the issue? And also, even though the checkpoint is failed, but we didn't fail to send any record out. Does this mean the transaction took more than 10 mins to finish which cause the checkpoint failed?

Comment: That does seem to be the case. In which case, it may suffice to increase the timeout.